# How to use InputFilterManager to construct custom InputFilters in Zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

ZF2 documentation says following on [defult services documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html);

> *InputFilterManager, mapping to Zend\Mvc\Service\InputFilterManagerFactory. This creates and returns
>   an instance of Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterPluginManager, which can be
>   used to manage and persist input filter instances.*

I have a custom zf2 inputfilter class and i'm adding filters and validators inside init() method like following;

```
namespace Application\Filter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class GlassFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'glassname',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array( 'name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('min' => 3),
                ),
        ));
}
```

Also i added following key to my module.config.php

```
'filters' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'glassfilter' => '\Application\Filter\GlassFilter',
    ),
),
```

My question is, how can i construct my **GlassFilter** using **InputFilterManager**? Is this a correct approach? I found [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/fw-general@lists.zend.com/msg33992.html) but i want to understand relation between custom InputFilters and InputFilterManager.

Comment: If im not mistaken, as long as you register it, it should be as simple as `array('name' => 'glassfilter')` under the `'filters'`-key

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, after spending 3 bloody hours (thanks to incredible(!) documentation) I figured it out. I'm writing my solution as an answer, hopefully it will help others who want to write their custom inputfilters.

1. You should register your custom inputfilter in `module.config.php` by **input_filters** top key, not filter, filters, filter_manger, filtermanager etc..
2. Extend default `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter` when writing your own `GlassFilter`.
3. Write your filters inside the `init()` method of `GlassFilter`, not in the `__constructor()`. It will be called automatically after construction.
4. Then get it anywhere via `inputfiltermanager`, not `servicemanager` directly.

Config example:

```
'input_filters' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'glassfilter' => '\Application\Filter\GlassFilter',
     ),
),
```

Usage example:

```
$glassfilter = $serviceLocator->get('InputFilterManager')->get('glassfilter');
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for number `4`! As for `1` you can also alternatively use the `Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\FilterProviderInterface` / `getFilterConfig()` in `Module.php`.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. In my case the `init()` function was not being triggered. This made it work.