# zf2 Trying to inject input filter into service

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm attempting to create a custom filter and inject it into a service via factory.

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter; 
class WSRequestFilter extends InputFilter{

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function init(){
        $this->add( array(
            'name' => 'apiVersion',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                array('name' => 'Real'),
...
```

In Module.php...

```
public function getServiceConfig(){
    return array(
        ...
        'factories' => array(
            'Puma\Service\WebServiceLayer' => function($sm) {
                $wsRequestFilter = new Filter\WSRequestFilter();
                $wsRequestFilter->init();
                $wsl = new Service\WebServiceLayer($wsRequestFilter);
                return $wsl;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

But I get service not found exception when executing `$wsRequestFilter->init();`.  I have also tried to initialize the filter using the `InputFilterManager` similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606109/how-to-use-inputfiltermanager-to-construct-custom-inputfilters-in-zf2) but I got a service not found trying to access the manager via `$serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')`.  I think I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init()` method invoked automatically by InputFilterManager just after the filter object created. You don't need to invoke manually.

Add this to your module configuration:

```
'input_filters' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'ws-request-filter' => '\YourModule\Filter\WSRequestFilter',
     ),
),
```

And change your service factory like below:

```
public function getServiceConfig(){
    return array(
        ...
        'factories' => array(
            'Puma\Service\WebServiceLayer' => function($sm) {
                $filter = $sm->get('InputfilterManager')->get('ws-request-filter')
                $wsl = new \YourModule\Service\WebServiceLayer($filter);
                return $wsl;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I tried this, and I feel like it should work, but I'm getting a ServiceNotFoundException when I try to create the filter the way you did.  I split it out into two lines and it looks like `get('ws-request-filter')` is causing it.  I have checked the module.config.php multiple times to make sure the syntax is correct and there are no mispellings.

Comment: Okay, found the mistake.  I didn't even realize I was invoking a service within my InputFilter.  The service that didn't exist was in InputFilter->add. Thanks for your help.